# iOS How to reset CoreData schema when no versioning was done and the schema changed from the published one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I need to find a way to delete the user current schema on the published app and recreate the one with the latest changes. I wasn't creating versions for the schema when I was developing new functionalities and now I can't go back to the original schema to make a migration.

In this case, data loss is not a problem. I just need the app to start from scratch when the user updates its app.

Thanks.

Comment: U either go for Core Data migration or the user need to delete the app from device before updating the new version of app..(Overriding is not possible without using Core Data Migration)

Comment: I was fearing that. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You don't need to delete the app. If you are happy to lose the current data, you can just delete the current database when the app launches (first time after upgrading) and CoreData will build a new empty DB with the new schema.